# How can I extract the exact part of the text on the cell of google sheet when the text can change?

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google Sheets spreadsheet, I have the cell A1 with value `"people 12-14 ABC"`. I want to extract the exact match "ABC" into another cell. The contents of cell A1 can change, e.g. to `"woman 60+ ABCD"`. For this input, I would want to extract "ABCD". If A1 was instead `"woman 12-20 CAE"`, I would want "CAE".

There are 5 possible strings that the last part may be: (ABC, ABCD, AB, CAE, C), while the first portions are very numerous (~400 possibilities).

How can I determine which of the 5 strings is in A1?

Comment: Which [functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)  have you tried using?

Comment: I have tried REGEXEXTRACT but when I have ABC or ABCD the results is ABC      =SI.ERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D3;"ABC"); "Check")

Comment: the first part has letters and number, I could put lower letters in the first part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee well-formatted input, this is simply a matter of splitting the contents of A1 into its component parts (e.g. "gender_filter", "age range", and "my 5 categories"), and selecting the appropriate index of the resultant array of strings.

To convert a cell's contents into an array of that content, the [`SPLIT()` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) can be used.

```
B1 = SPLIT(A1, " ")
```

would put entries into B1, C1, and D1, where D1 has the value you want - provided your gender filter and age ranges.

Since you probably don't want to have those excess junk values, you want to contain the result of split entirely in B1. To do this, we need to pass the array generated by `SPLIT` to a function that can take a range or array input. As a bonus, we want to sub-select a part of this range (specifically, the last one). For this, we can use the [`INDEX()` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)

```
B1 = INDEX(SPLIT(A1, " "), 1, COUNTA(SPLIT(A1, " ")))
```

This tells the `INDEX` function to access the first row and the last column of the range produced by `SPLIT`, which for the inputs you have provided, is "ABC", "ABCD", and "CAE".

Answer (score 1):

If the first part "only" has lower case or numbers and the last part "only" UPPER case,

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D3;"[^A-E]";)
```

Anchor: Space

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A31;"\s([A-E]+)$")
```